# Reference two sequences in for loop, then update first sequence based on their conditions - python

Tags: pandas, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, sequences

Trying to reference two sequences in a python for loop such as:

```
for (col1_row, col2_row) in (df.col1, df.col2)
```

Then check if two conditions are true:

```
if col1_row = 'nan' and col2_row = '1000 Main Street'
```

Then update the corresponding cell in df.col1 with a set value:

```
df.col1 == 'Chucky Cheeze Restaurant'
```

Does not have to be a for loop, but I thought I'd explain it this way. Looking for fastest, most efficient method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not use loops, because slow, better is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with boolean mask:

```
mask = (df.col1 == 'nan') & (df.col2 == '1000 Main Street')
#for oldier pandas versions
#mask = df.col1.isnull() & (df.col2 == '1000 Main Street')
df.col1 = np.where(mask, 'Chucky Cheeze Restaurant', df.col1)
```

Or:

```
mask = df.col2 == '1000 Main Street'
df.loc[mask, 'col1'] = df.loc[mask, 'col1'].fillna('Chucky Cheeze Restaurant')
```

Comment: @spacedustpi what about `mask = (df.col1 =='nan' ) & (df.col2 == '1000 Main Street')`?

Comment: it is weird,  there is no trailing whitespace? how working `print ((df.col1 =='nan' ) )` and `print (,((df.col2 == '1000 Main Street'))`? It seems some data problem.

Comment: Wondering why second method is not working. Also, why would adding parenz change execution result with first method?

Comment: I can see the utility of this method. I can add more sequences by adding more to 'mask =...' joined with '&'. This will be the gift that keeps on giving.